# OData EnableAlternateKeys/EnableEnumPrefixFree/EnableUnqualifiedNameCall

Tags: .net, odata

I am working on Web Api with OData. In 5,7.0, I saw there is a new feature AlternateKey released. But when I enabled it, I found it doesn't work.

When I use github sample https://github.com/OData/ODataSamples/tree/master/WebApi/v4/ODataAlternateKeySamples/ODataAlternateKeySamples, I added two lines in WebApiConfig.

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.EnableEnumPrefixFree(true);
            config.EnableUnqualifiedNameCall(true);
            config.EnableAlternateKeys(true);
            config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", AlternateKeyEdmModel.GetEdmModel());
        }
    }
```

Then I got the following exception.

> The path template 'Customers(SSN={ssn})' on the action
>   'GetCustomerBySSN' in controller 'Customers' is not a valid OData path
>   template.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This an issue and I have created for you to track, pull request is also welcome.
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/636